# Is it possible to change the Xcode's iOS DeviceSupport default folder location?

Tags: xcode

I want it to point to an external drive and save some memory on main drive.. please assist.. so far it seems that it's impossible to do so. Only Archive and DerivedData can be configured via Locations preference..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such option. But you can symlink the destination with `ln -s` command. Something like this:

```
% ln -s /ExternalDrive/DeviceSupport/ ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/
```

So,

1. Close the Xcode
2. Move the `DeviceSupport` directory to the destination where you want to store it
3. Symlink the new destination
4. Launch Xcode and check that everything works as expected

PS Check the [How to Create Symbolic Links at Command Line of Mac OS X](https://osxdaily.com/2015/08/06/make-symbolic-links-command-line-mac-os-x/) guide if you need more information about linking.

Comment: That was helpful. Exactly. Thank you.